# ldap query syntax to exclude alpha characters

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to make adjustments to this `LDAP` query so that any `employeeIDs` that contain only numbers are included in the filter and anything else is skipped. `(!employeeID=\00)`will grab any `ID` that is not blank or null I believe, but how do I test for alpha or just numeric characters in AD? Thanks

```
-LdapFilter "(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)

(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)

(!objectClass=inetOrgPerson))(sAMAccountName=s0*)(!sAMAccountName=*-d)(!sAMAccountName=*-e)

(!sAMAccountName=*-a)(!Name=Test*)(!Name=v-*)(!employeeID=\00))”
```

Comment: You don't need all those extra `&`s. LDAP filter operators aren't binary, they can take any number of operands, that's why they use the prefix notation. For example `(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we can use the search filter to filter out non-digit values.
Found no related filters here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Instead you may use a simpler filter to get all users, add those attributes (e.g. employeeID, sAMAccountName, etc.) to the properties-to-load list. And then filter that on client side.

Besides, filter like `attr=*sth` will be slow. The index only helps in equal (`attr=sth`) and start-with (`attr=sth*`) ones.

Comment: Here is the full script I'm trying to help edit. I'm not super great with Power Shell, but I am able to do LDAP queries ok.

Comment: Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement $people = Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 0 -includeallproperties -LdapFilter "(&((objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!objectClass=inetOrgPerson))(sAMAccountName=s0*)(!sAMAccountName=*-d)(!sAMAccountName=*-e)(!sAMAccountName=*-a)(!Name=Test*)(!Name=v-*)(!employeeID=\00))"
$people | select dn,sn,title,company,employeeID,@{Label="SamAccountName";Expression={$_.SamAccountName.ToLower()}} | ConvertTo-Csv -Notypeinformation | select -Skip 2 > C:\test.csv

Comment: I decided to dump from AD and sort on employeeID then add to the LDAP (!employeeID=*s)(!employeeID=a*)(!employeeID=c*)(!employeeID=d*)(!employeeID=m*)(!employeeID=n*)(!employeeID=p*)(!employeeID=s*). I know it's far from pretty...